# Laravel 4: load class dynamically from string in database

Tags: php, class, dynamic, laravel, laravel-4

I wish i knew how to search for this question / phrase it more appropriately. This hampered my search for prior questions; bear with me if this is a duplicate.

**See the update / edits at the *bottom* of this post**

**Background / what i'm trying to do:**

I have a URL that looks a lot like this:

http://myapp.com/calculate/`$fileID`/`$calculateID`

`$fileID` and `$calculateID` are keys that I use to keep track of a data set and something I call a 'calculation'.  Essentially, that URL says perform `$calculateID` on the data in `$fileID`.

I go to my database (mongo) and ask for a php class name or sring or file path or what have you that matches `$calculateID`.  For example's sake let's say the table looks like this:

```
 +-----+-------------------+
 | _id |     phpFile       |
 +-----+-------------------+
 |   1 | basicCalcs.php    |
 |   2 | advancedCalcs.php |
 |   3 | summaryCalcs.php  |
 +-----+-------------------+
```

**Note:** is is safe to assume that each file in the `phpFile` column has a common interface / set of public methods.

**Example:**

http://myapp.com/calculate/23/2

would go to the database, get the data from set `23` and then load up the functions in `advancedCalcs.php`.  Once `advancedCalcs.php` has been loaded, a function within will receive the data.  From there, a set of calculations and transformations are performed on the data.

**My question**

My question is what is a 'laravel 4 friendly' way to dynamically load up `advancedCalcs.php` and feed the data into a set of methods?  Is there a way to lazy load this type of thing.  Currently, i am only aware of the very unsophisticated `require_once()` method.  I would really like to avoid this as i am convinced that laravel 4 has functionality to dynamically load an underlying class and hook it up to a common interface.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Antonio Carlos Ribeiro, i was able to make some progress.

After running dump-autoload command, my `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file has a few new entries that look like this:

```
'AnalyzeController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/AnalyzeController.php',
'AppName\\Calc\\CalcInterface' => $baseDir . '/app/calculators/CalcInterface.php',
'AppName\\Calc\\basicCalcs' => $baseDir . '/app/calculators/basicCalcs.php',
```

With code like the sample below, i can create an instance of the basicCalcs class:

```
$className = "AppName\\Calc\\basicCalcs";

$instance = new $className; 

var_dump($instance);
```

Where the `basicCalcs.php` file looks like this:

```
//PATH: /app/calculators/basicCalcs.php
<?php namespace Reporter\Calc;


class basicCalcs {


    public function sayHi(){
        echo("hello world! i am basicCalcs");
    }

};

?>
```

**Updated question:**
How can i create an alias similar to the `AnalyzeController` entry in  `autoload_classmap.php` rather than having to refer to `basicCalcs.php` with a full namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your library folder to your composer.json autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/extended",
        "app/calculators",  <------- This is where you put all your calculators
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Update your autoloaded classes:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If you want to be sure it did worked, check if your classes are autoloaded opening the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

To instantiate them dinamically you better have this as a table class names:

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| _id |     phpFile       |  namespace        |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|   1 | basicCalcs        | Reporter\Calc\    |
|   2 | advancedCalcs     | Reporter\Calc\    |
|   3 | summaryCalcs      | Reporter\Calc\    |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Then you just have to use it

```
class CalculateController extends Controller {

    public function calculate($fileID, $calculateID)
    {
        $file = phpFile::find($fileID);

        $className = $file->namespace . $file->phpFile;

        $calculator = new $className; //// <--- this thing will be autoloaded

        return $calculator->calculate( $calculateID );
    }

}
```

I'm assuming your calculators are all:

```
class basicCalcs {

    public function calculate($calculateID)
    {
        return performCalculation( $calculateID ); /// something like this
    }

}
```

And your router is somethink like

```
Route::get('/calculate/{fileID}/{calculateID}', array('as'=>'calculate', 'uses'=>'CalculateController@calculate'));
```

Comment: **Thanks**.  I see waht you're trying to do, but the find() method does not exist in laravel 4's Filesystem class.  I can't seem to find much mention of it on php.net, either.  I was able to get what i needed by doing this `$className = "The\\Namespace\\path\\Inautoload_classmap.php";
$instance = new $className; `


This **works** but is there any way i set up aliases for the namespace?

Comment: Sorry about that File::, I changed it to phpFile to be clearer, because it should be your phpFile model, where you store your filenames. As long as your classes are appearing in the autoload_classmap.php file, you don't need the namespaces, unless you need them to organize your code, of course.

Comment: `namespace` is required if you want to use `psr0`.

Comment: Ah, Antonio, i understand now.  My classes are appearing in the autoload file, but only by namespace. I have updated my original post to reflect this. I can load up the class by referring to it with it's full namespace, so i might end up just storing that in the database

Comment: `namespace` is required if you are autoloading via autoload:psr0, but if your are using `"autoload": { "classmap": ["your/path"] }`, it isn't, at least not in Laravel 4.

Comment: I think you have two options: add the namespace '<?php namespace Reporter\Calc;' to your controller and then refer to it also in your routes or `$class = 'Reporter\Calc\' . $file->phpFile;`. Just edited to support your namespaces.

Comment: **THANKS** this is very close to the approach i ended up taking.  many thanks!

Comment: Hi, useful answer; I'm doing something similar but in my case files may be added or removed from `calculators` folder dynamically, I tested `Classmap` and it seems that it just auto-loads files that have been in the folder, and gives a `Class 'newCalc' not found` error when I try to instantiate `newClac` class defined in `newCalc.php` file in same `calculator` folder. Is there any workaround for my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `Laravel4` the file `composer.json` is responsible for this, following is an example

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Notice the `autoload` section where `classmap` is used to to tell `laravel4` from which folders it should load classes and also which file should it load. For example, `"app/controllers",` will be used to load all classes from the `app/controllers` folder and `"app/tests/TestCase.php"` will make `Laravel4` to autoload the class `TestCase.php` from `app/tests/` folder. So, add your library folder in to the `classmap` section. Once you have added your folder path in `autoload -> classmap` section then you have to run

```
composer dumpautoload // or
composer dump-autoload
```

from the command line.

Comment: Thanks; this got me going in the right direction.  my original question has been updated to reflect where i am now getting stuck.